# GridFs bug with java driver

Tags: mongodb, gridfs

I am using Gridfs for storing a big file in mongodb.
This is my code to insert the file:

```
 GridFS bigFile = new GridFS(db, "35");
File f = new File(path+"/element.son");
GridFSInputFile gfsFile = bigFile.createFile(f);
gfsFile.setFilename("35");
gfsFile.save();
```

The file was successfully inserted intact, if I try to show it through the restful interface I had the follow response:

```
{
 "offset" : 0,
 "rows": [
    { "_id" : { "$oid" : "536ad33c300433edfe512724" }, "chunkSize" : 261120, "length" :             
    17647218, "md5" : "a86b60fb2d219d26b37256c89d1bb7f2", "filename" : "35", "contentType" :   
    null, "uploadDate" : { "$date" : 1399509820201 }, "aliases" : null }
  ],
  "total_rows" : 1 ,
  "query" : {} ,
  "millis" : 0
 }
```

Now, I want to delete this bucket, this is my code:

```
GridFS gridFs = new GridFS(db, "35");
GridFSDBFile fi = gridFs.findOne("35");
GridFSDBFile file = gridFs.findOne(new ObjectId(fi.getId().toString()));
gridFs.remove(file);
```

Apparently the file has been deleted infact the response is:

```
{
 "offset" : 0,
 "rows": [], 
 "total_rows" : 0 ,
 "query" : {} ,
 "millis" : 0
}
```

but, if I show the collections in my console I have still my bucket (35.files,35.chunks).

Why after the remove in the console I have still this bucket?
is it a bug or I haven't understood some stuff?

Answer (score 0):

I have sent an email to the community of mongodb and they said me that my question isn't a bug.
For more details:
https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/JAVA-1205?filter=-2